# Any way to tell which version of Windows 7 is burnt to my DVD?

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check if Win 7 disk is 64bit and what version?](https://superuser.com/questions/189671/how-to-check-if-win-7-disk-is-64bit-and-what-version)

I burnt a copy of Windows 7 from my valid MSDN subscription, only thing is I forgot to label it. Now I would like to know if it is the 32Bit version or the 64Bit version.

Is there any way to tell what version of Windows 7 is installed on this DVD I burnt?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talking about Win7 Professional, my x64 version is about 3GB and my x86 version is about 2.3GB. The 64-bit version also has an additional file in the root of the DVD called bootmgr.efi.

Comment: I confirm for bootmgr.efi