# How to know the Edition of Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I have a Windows 7 DVD. However I don't know which edition it contain. Is there any way to find the edition(Like Ultimate, Home Premium, Home Basic) without installing it?  Can anybody help me?

Comment: The DVDs can contain multiple editions.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/189671/how-to-check-if-win-7-disk-is-64bit-and-what-version

Answer (score 5):

Put the disc in and load it up, it should tell you the version before you actually install it